# Redirect Expired HTTPs to HTTP

Tags: iis, coldfusion

Our clients website SSL expired recently and now the client wants `https` to redirect to `http` temporary until his SSL is up again.

Is there a way in ColdFusion or IIS to do this. E.g. `https://www.example.com` redirect to `http://www.example.com`

Please help, its hard to find resources regarding this.

Comment: You can probably just do the opposite of this: http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you want to get them back on https as soon as possible, this might work:

Put the following at the start of the `onRequestStart` method in your `application.cfc`:

```
<cfif isBoolean(CGI.server_port_secure) AND CGI.server_port_secure>
    <cflocation url="http://www.example.com" addtoken="false" />
</cfif>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but doesn't work. Any more information you can give me.

Comment: If this doesn't work, you're better off doing it in IIS, not CF.

Comment: You could also try comparing `CGI.SERVER_PORT`. Typically http is port 80, and 443 for ssl. Redirect as necessary.

Comment: you also want to make sure you don't have any CF code or IIS settings that is forcing http traffic back onto https.

Comment: This won't work, because for them to get this far, the server would need to have offered a valid ssl cert already (or the client would have to ignore the warnings). Come to think of it, my answer may not work for the same reason. The whole point of SSL is to make sure somebody without the right cert can't direct you somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in IIS, not ColdFusion:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/05/23/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher.aspx